# Kotlin EditText.setText() is buggy

Tags: android, kotlin

Simple yet annoying problem

Im using Kotlin with ViewBinding and ViewModels. Everything works fine, even the Timber logs respond with the correct strings in Logcat window. Just the .setText() is working only 1 out of 4 times as expected. Same result goes to .append().

Here is my fragment :

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.getSelectedNote { selectedNote ->
            selectedNote?.let { note ->
// clears labels ( works )
                binding.inputTitle.text.clear()
                binding.inputContents.text.clear()
// outputs correct string in logs
                Timber.d("notes title : " + note.title)
// works 1 of 4 times
                binding.inputTitle.text.append(note.title)
// outputs correct string in logs
                Timber.d("notes contents : " + note.contents)
// works 1 of 4 times
                binding.inputContents.setText(note.contents)
            }
        }
    }
```

Has anyone experienced something like this and found a solution ?

P.S. i did checkout other threads, they couldnt solve my problem.

Comment: having you tried `binding.executePendingBindings()` at the end?

Comment: Yup, that was it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Shoutout to @Mark Keen from comment section under my question.

```
binding.executePendingBindings()
```

solved my 'bug', i just added it at the end of text bindings and it solved everything.